# CypherSyntaxError:The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported. Please use `$param` instead. in noemodel v4.0.1 not in neo4j v4.1

Tags: django-models, neo4j, graph-databases, neomodel

This issue is resolved in *neo4j v4.1* update. But my question is related to **neomodel v4.0.1**. How do we resolve this issue in neomodel v4.0.1.

My queries: I have **models.py** as

```
from neomodel import StructuredNode, StringProperty, UniqueIdProperty()

class Person(StructuredNode):
  person_id = UniqueIdProperty()
  person_name = StringProperty()
```

when i execute

> `python manage.py install_labels`
> it works fine with no errors

```
$ python manage.py install_labels
Setting up indexes and constraints...

Found django_neomodel.DjangoNode
 ! Skipping class django_neomodel.DjangoNode is abstract
Found neo4japp.models.Person
 + Creating unique constraint for person_id on label Person for class neo4japp.models.Person

Finished 2 classes.
```

But when I create its object like

> `modiji = Person(person_id='1', person_name='modiji').save()`

it gives me this error

```
CypherSyntaxError: The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported. Please use `$param` instead (line 1, column 18 (offset: 17)) "CREATE (n:Person {create_params}) RETURN n"
```

As in OGM we can't manipulate cypher queries - how do I make it work? Please help.

I want to make use of OGM and don't want to hard code cypher queries to make my code effectively using django framework & neomodel.

If not then what is the alternative to neomodel to use OGM queries like the one in ORM so as to ease the database querying stuff?

Comment: the answers which i get mostly is 

`Parameters should be prefixed with $ in 4.0 instead of curly brackets. Just write $parametername instead of {parametername}`

But how do i do this in neomodel using OGM features?

Comment: Are you saying neomodel 4.0.0 or 4.0.1 solves the issue? If so, what prevents you from upgrading to one of these versions?

Comment: sorry my bad. I am using neomodel v4.0.1(updated the question) & still the same issue. Is anybody able to add objects using models in neomodel?. I am trying to populate graph in neo4j using django but its showing CypherSyntaxError as mentioned above.  

Actually neo4j has few answers to replace {} with $ but how to do the same in neomodel?