# How to pass the whole map as a property when using apoc.load.csv while creating nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to create nodes by loading a csv file. Since I wanted to exclude some columns I decided to use `apoc.load.csv` instead of the simpler `LOAD CSV` command.

I wanted to have all the columns present as corresponding property value for the nodes. However I am not able to figure out how to do it. When the columns are less you can hardcode it, but in my real dataset I have more than 60 columns so I was hoping that there would be a programmatic way to achieve what I want to do.

Demo Dataset you can use `data.csv` -

```
name,age,beverage,country_from,fruit
Selma,9,Soda,RU,Apple
Rana,12,Tea,USA,Orange
Selina,19,Cola,CA,Guava
```

What I have tried so far that doesn't work yet -

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('data.csv', {header:true, ignore:['beverage'], 
mapping:{
    age: {type:'int'},
    country_from: {name: "country"}
    }
})
YIELD map as row
CREATE (e:Entity $row)
CREATE (f:Fruit {name: row.fruit})
CREATE (c:Country {name: row.country_from})
MERGE (e:Entity)-[:EATS]->(f:Fruit)
MERGE (e:Entity)-[:IS_FROM]->(c:Country)
RETURN e,c,f
```

**Expected Output**:
The graphdatabase has the Entity nodes with properties `name`,`age`,`country`,`fruit`

Initially I was using `{row}` but then I got the error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246248/cyphersyntaxerrorthe-old-parameter-syntax-param-is-no-longer-supported-ple)

```
The old parameter syntax `{param}` is no longer supported. Please use `$param` instead
```

so I switched to using `$row` but then I get -

```
Expected parameter(s): row
```

I have followed the ideas from the following links -

1. https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.4/export-import/load-csv/
2. https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/load-csv/